Data Ingestion for the RAG from Dynamo DB to AuroraDB with pgVector to store embeddings
I have data stored in my DynamoDB which is frequently updated through back-end services. Now I want to create a PG vector based AuroraDB vector database for storing embeddings, which I want to be automatically updated whenever there is the change in the DynamoDB.
I thought about using the EventBridge but need more suggestion on that.
My aim is to create the new embeddings everytime there is the change (Upsert) in the DynamoDB and store them in the PG Vector Database. So that I can perform the RAG on latest embeddings to so the answer from LLM must be context aware.
In the phase of architectural designing and ideation of this feature.

I'm not sure if you're requirement is strictly dependent on pg_vector.
For me, I would use ZeroETL with OpenSearch(AOS) which automatically replicates mutations to your data into the AOS domain. AOS can then integrate with SageMaker or Bedrock to generate an embedding on the fields you wish to embed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/OpenSearchIngestionForDynamoDB.html
If you really want to use pg_vector then you can use DynamoDB streams with a Lambda consumer, the Lambda will reach out to SageMaker or Bedrock and generate embeddings and then push those changes into Aurora/RDS.

It is really helpful
